# Simon Simpson programmer

Tags: reference-request, programming

In Raymond Smullyan's book *Satan, Cantor, and Infinity*, the Sorcerer refers to a method of achieving self-reference which is "remarkably similar to Simon Simpson's method of programming" (near the end of the chapter entitled Self-reference and Cross-reference). I have tried looking him up but cannot find anything about a programmer called Simon Simpson - does anyone know anything about him?

Comment: I wonder whether the book is referring to this [simon](https://imgur.com/gallery/8mA6rCV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From page $135$ of Smullyan (right before the Solutions at the end of Chapter 12):

> "Tomorrow," said the Sorcerer, "before we leave this island, I would
>   like us to visit the station of Simon Simpson, who is the youngest and
>   most progressive roboteer on this island.  I've heard he is a bit on
>   the vain side, but also that his program system is a very simple and
>   elegant one, and definitely worth learning."

See also the entirety of Chapter 13.